# How to set a form field value by using setter in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form that have an own model contains setters and getters like that:

```
class CommentAdd
{
    protected $content;

    protected $yandexCaptcha;

    protected $isAnonymous;

    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setYandexCaptcha(YandexCaptcha $yandexCaptcha) {
        $this->yandexCaptcha = $yandexCaptcha;
    }

    public function getYandexCaptcha() {
        return $this->yandexCaptcha;
    }

    public function setIsAnonymous($isAnonymous) {
        $this->isAnonymous = $isAnonymous;
    }

    public function getIsAnonymous() {
        return $this->isAnonymous;
    }
}
```

So what is the way to set any field value by calling setter? I know the way to get any value by using getter ($form->getData()->getValue()) but I don't know the way to set.

**Update:**

The form object is created so:

```
    $commentAddForm = $this->createForm(new CommentAddType(), new CommentAdd(), [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('blog_comment_add', ['id' => $id]),
        'is_authenticated' => $this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')
    ]);

//That will return value by using the getter getContent from CommentAdd model
$commentAddForm->getData()->getContent();

//That will return value without using getter from the model
$commentAddForm->get('content')->getData();

//Now I want to know the way to set any data by using setter from the model
$commentAddForm-> ???
```

P.S. I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: Easiest way is to create a form type.  Read through: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: I have a form type that have own model.

Comment: If I use $form->get('field')->getData() that will return data without using getter from a model. But I have found the way to get by using getter (I show that on the post), now I want to know the similar way for set.

Answer (score 0):

You set the data on the object instance from which you create the form; not on the form fields themselves. As per the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html):

```
$task = new Task();
$task->setTask('Write a blog post');
$task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
    ->add('task', 'text')
    ->add('dueDate', 'date')
    ->add('save', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```